# Compiler can't find 'aligned_alloc' function

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, c++17

I'm trying to launch the example code from [aligned alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int* p1 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(10*sizeof *p1));
    std::printf("default-aligned address:   %p\n", static_cast<void*>(p1));
    std::free(p1);

    int* p2 = static_cast<int*>(std::aligned_alloc(1024, 1024));
    std::printf("1024-byte aligned address: %p\n", static_cast<void*>(p2));
    std::free(p2);
}
```

My compilers give me this error:

```
$ g++-mp-8 main.cpp -std=c++17
main.cpp:10:38: error: no member named 'aligned_alloc' in namespace 'std'
    int* p2 = static_cast<int*>(std::aligned_alloc(1024, 1024));
```

I am working with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and tried to compile this code with Macport's GCC 7.3.0, 8.2.0 and CLang (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0), they all produce the same error.

Edit: It doesn't work with either `std::` present or not.

Edit2: I installed macOS Mojave and that did not fix the problem. I hoped it'll reinstall macOS's toolchain but it didn't. So I guess I cannot accept provided answers until I get a more specific one.

Comment: That example code that you linked doesn't have `aligned_alloc` in `std`. Does it work if you remove the `std::` in front of `aligned_alloc`?

Comment: Please, provide [mcve]

Comment: @Blaze No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Blaze By including `cstdlib`, Verloren got the C library features from `stdlib.h` placed in namespace `std`. In fact, clicking on the link at the bottom of the ref page to the C++ equivalent shows the same example as is here in the question.

Comment: It's almost certainly just a missing feature in your toolchain. Can you link to its documentation/status? e.g. XCode 9 on High Sierra also doesn't have `std::optional` and some other things, despite notionally being C++17-compatible.

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You mean the documentation for my libc++/libstdc++ ? How can I check their versions?

Comment: @Verloren: No idea, sorry!

Comment: Note that the C++ standard library has aligned allocation facilities

Comment: @M.M Could you please explain what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Verloren the function you're trying to use is from the C standard library, which is included in C++ for compatibility reasons, but the C++ standard library also has functions to do aligned allocation. You could use those instead if your goal is actually just do do aligned allocation (the question suggests you want to use `std::aligned_alloc` specifically for some reason)

Comment: @M.M If you could provide any example of such functions that would be very nice, I can't find any on my own.

Comment: `operator new`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not using macOS but I have similar problems on linux using a custom g++. If you look at the `cstdlib` header, there is something like

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L && defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_ALIGNED_ALLOC)
  using ::aligned_alloc;
#endif
```

So `aligned_alloc` is only pulled into the `std` namespace if C++17 is available and glibcxx supports it. You can check `x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h` (or something similar on macOS) if `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_ALIGNED_ALLOC` is defined. If not your glibc version is too old.

For clang and the libc++ implementation `aligned_alloc` is available if `_LIBCPP_HAS_C11_FEATURES` is defined which again depends on a recent version of glibc.

As an alternative you can use [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/align/reference.html#align.reference.functions.aligned_alloc).

Comment: That is most probably the case, because in my `c++config.h` (located in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/`) don't even contain `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_ALIGNED_ALLOC` or `_LIBCPP_HAS_C11_FEATURES`. However, I have no idea how to update glibc for Mac, and googling did'nt help much. I'll try to install Mojave and hope that will fix it.

Comment: As I said, I am not using macOS, so it may differ there. Instlaling a custom glibc is rather demanding. I switched to `boost::aligned_alloc` if `std::aligned_alloc` is not available, see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/align/reference.html#align.reference.functions.aligned_alloc).

Comment: boost is not an option for me, unfortunately. And finding an alternative is indeed helpful for me, but it's not solving the problem in question.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer mentions it, using `boost::align::aligned_alloc` solves the problem.

To fix the error without source modification, just add the following on top of the file:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <boost/align/aligned_alloc.hpp>
using boost::alignment::aligned_alloc;
#endif
```